# In postgres how do I add index to existing table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

In postgres how do I add index to existing table?

I tried following but it's not working:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING btree(a_column);
```

and then this:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING btree(a_column);
```

But neither works.

I am using ant to do a db migration. And when I do `ant db-migrate-apply-postgresql` I keep getting the error

```
 [echo] ERROR:  relation "my_index" already exists
```

Comment: The syntax you have there *should* work (Two identical examples?). Else you need to include the **error message** to make this a useful question. [Or refer to the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: I edit to add context and include error message.

Comment: Error seems clear. Tried using other name for the index?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, this error message:

> *ERROR:  relation "my_index" already exists*

is pretty clear, isn't it.

You are trying to create an index with the name of an existing index or table. 
You need to use a different name.

Comment: But in reality it's not true. I have no such table or index.

Comment: @user1467855: apparently you have.

Comment: actually I am trying to add indexes to three different tables. For each table, the index would have the same name, "my_index". But ant is not adding index to any of the tables. Just as three different tables can have fields named `id`, this should not be a problem.

Comment: @user1467855: an index name - just like a table name - must be unique. You cannot have three indexes with the same name (just as you cannot have three tables with the same name)

Comment: @user1467855 No database will let you use the same name. The index is scoped outside of the Table. Columns are scoped inside the table. That's why all tables can have a column with the same name.

Comment: @user1467855: Make it a habit to prefix the indexes with the tablename `a_my_index`, `b_my_index`, ..

Comment: @Andrew Finnell, I try to give you upvote, but apparently I am too new here for that privilege. Thanks!