# Why can't two tables have an index of the same name?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm creating indexes on two separate tables in the same DB (PostgreSQL), and I got an error saying that an index already exists.  This was true, however, the index existed on a different table.  After changing the name, it worked.

I'm wondering why this is the case?  Why are databases designed such that two tables can't have the same name of an index?

I found two sources that answer this, although the answers are different.  One is for MySQL, the other is for Postgres:

[In postgres how do I add index to existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353347/in-postgres-how-do-i-add-index-to-existing-table)

[Same index name for two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352055/same-index-name-for-two-tables)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same index name for two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352055/same-index-name-for-two-tables)

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate, @JarrodRoberson.  The answer to that question states that you can have indexes of the same name whereas my question implies that my tables can't have the same name.  I guess it's a PostgreSQL specific issue? I've removed the MySQL tag

Comment: You would need to ask the people who did the initial design for Postgres (or Oracle). Some DBMS do allow the same index name for different tables (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) some don't (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird). It's a choice the developers did back when they created the DBMS.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name.  Lol, I guess I was hoping one of the creators of Postgres would come across this post :p .  But I think RudiDudi answered my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have two indexes of the same name. They just can't be in the same schema.  Just like you can have two tables of the same name, but not in the same schema.

```
sandbox=# create schema test;
CREATE SCHEMA
sandbox=# create table public.a (a_id integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# create table test.a (a_id integer not null);
CREATE TABLE
sandbox=# create index a_idx on public.a (a_id);
CREATE INDEX
sandbox=# create index a_idx on test.a (a_id);
CREATE INDEX
```

This reflects a decision by the PostgreSQL designers. SQL standards don't deal with creating indexes.

Answer (score 4):

Because the index is stored in the table pg_class. Within that table there is a composite key comprised of the index name and the namespace, which is why you cannot have two indexes with the same name belonging to the same namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Cause it is a db object, like a table/view/procedure.
it's the same for two tables with same name but different columns, or two procedures with same name but different parameters.

Comment: so indexes are kind of like global objects in the db environment?  I imagine them being subsidiaries of their tables, thus allowing them to have the same name.